# group by clause in bigquery not working

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery

When running this query:

```
SELECT 
    date( time_ts ), 
    count(*) 
FROM 
    [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.comments]
GROUP BY 
    date( time_ts)
```

I get following error:

```
expression STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(INT64(PARSE_UTC_USEC(STRING([time_ts]))), '%Y-%m-%d') in GROUP BY is invalid
```

How do i rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an alias to the date(time_ts) field and then group by the alias instead so:

```
SELECT 
date( time_ts ) as date, 
count(*) as count 
FROM [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.comments] 
group by date
```

Comment: or you can use GROUP BY 1 :o)